# Why is there a conflict in the total size of file and the current position of pointer in Python File Handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Contents of my file below:

```
1   2   
34
56
78
```

Below is the code I have written:

```
file_name = "abc.txt"
file_mode = "r"
with open(file_name, file_mode) as f:
    my_list = list(f.read())
    print(my_list)
    print("length of the file is", len(my_list))
    print("position being told by .tell() method is", f.tell())
```

Output of the code:

```
['1', '\t', '2', '\t', '\n', '3', '4', '\n', '5', '6', '\n', '7', '8', '\n']
length of the file is 14
position being told by .tell() method is 18
```

Do you see what's wrong here? Why does the tell method return the position of pointer as 18, when the total length of the contents of my file is not more than 14?

Answer (score 1):

You opened the file in text mode, which converts `\r\n` in the file to `\n` in the value returned by `f.read()`. There are 4 lines, which matches the inconsistency.

Open it in binary mode and you'll get consistent results.

```
file_mode = "rb"
```